# Number of times the displacement of an object executing a simple harmonic motion becomes zero

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, frequency

I was solving some SHM problems when i came across this  particular question. It asked, what is the frequency of SHM of an object whose displacement becomes zero 200 times in one second. The answer is 100 Hz but I don't get it. In a SHM, the object passes through the mean position thrice: At the starting position, during the first crossing and at the ending position. So, using this logic, shouldn't the frequency be 200/3 Hz instead of 100 Hz. Please explain [NOTE: I AM IN HIGH SCHOOL SO PLEASE SIMPLIFY EVERYTHING AS I AM BAD AT PHYSICS]

Comment: For simplicity assume it to be zero $6$ times a second.  Draw a diagram starting from a non-zero position and do the counting of complete oscillations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "ending position" of one cycle is the "starting position" of the next cycle.  So you're double-counting these crossings.  There are really only two zero crossings *per cycle*.

Another way to look at this is to define one cycle to be between one moment of maximum (positive) displacement and the next moment of maximum displacement.  Viewed from this perspective it is more obvious that there are two zero crossings per cycle.

Comment: thanks, it helped a lot